# Facebook api : iterate through posts

Tags: php, facebook, loops, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get posts message and ids through a loop, eventually I will want to get posts' likes, but I'm not there yet, so one step at a time.

I'm getting my page's name, url, picture, description, fans and posts.
I then proceed in displaying them.
posts is apparently an Stdclass object, so to roughly display it print_r works.

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app','appsecret');


$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();


$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/myapp?fields=id,name,about,likes,link,,posts');
$response = $request->execute();

$content = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();


?>

<h1><?= $content['name'] ?></h1>

<p><img src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?= $content['id'] ?>/picture?width=180&height=180" /></p>
<p>About: <?= $content['about'] ?></p>

<p>fans: <?= $content['likes'] ?></p>

<p>url: <?= $content['link'] ?></p>

<p>posts: <?= print_r($content['posts']) ?></p>
```

So I tried doing a loop

```
foreach($content['posts'] as $post){
    echo $post['id'];
    echo $post['message']
}
```

However, I get indefined index errors for id and message, and while I roughly get why, I've not been able to solve it.

print_r on posts outputs something like this :

```
StdClass Object ( [data] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [message] => postmessage. [created_time] => 2017-06-28T13:00:00+0000 [id] => a_post_id )
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try with this: `foreach($content['posts']->data as $post){` (your array is in a property called `data` in your object)

Comment: haha guess I figured as the time as you posted :-) Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Figured out myself, but Kaddath also provided the correct way :

```
foreach ($content['posts']->data as $posts) { 

    echo "<p>posts id: $posts->id</p>";

    echo "<p>posts message: $posts->message</p>";
}
```